# File deleted and recreated has to be in separate revision?

Tags: mercurial

I had a CSS file from a previous revision called 'bootstrap.css'

I deleted the file and recreated a totally new file with the same name.

When I came to commit my changes, the deletion of the original bootstrap.css was detected. But the creation of the new file was not detected. Immediately after I committed, the new file was detected.

The only way I could find to get the new file into the repository was to do two separate commits.

Did I do something wrong? Is it a config issue? Or is it supposed to work like that?

(I was using TortoiseHg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mercurial does not maintain a *file identity*, so you cannot talk about the "old" `bootstrap.css` and the "new" `bootstrap.css`. To Mercurial, it's just data stored under the same file name. You'll see that

```
$ hg log bootstrap.css
```

will interleave the history of the two files — since there's really only one file in Mercurial's eyes.

This is normally fine and works like you would expect. You can run

```
$ hg remove bootstrap.css
$ echo '/* new and improved */' > bootstrap.css
$ hg add bootstrap.css
```

(or the equivalent from TortoiseHg) and the result is that `bootstrap.css` is modified:

```
$ hg status
M bootstrap.css
```

Modified just means that it's different compared to the parent revision.

Comment: Well that's what I've always thought, but how does that explain why no matter what I did, when I went to commit in Tortoise: my bootstrap.css was in red with a '!' next to it, even though there was a file called bootstrap.css in the file structure?

Comment: Because you'd done the equivalent of `hg remove bootstrap.css` in tortoisehg without doing the equivalent of `hg add bootstrap.css`.